Error message "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code." on table with empty cells
I want to post a question but there is no code!
I always get this error message and can't post it.
Finally I marked all text as code but this did not solve the problem.
Question:

MySQL Find commission rate for sales between commission table and sales table records
I have to pay commission to sales stuff depending on the customer number, optional on the product number, optional on a certain time range.
My commission table looks like this:

VPID=sales person ID,
KdID=customer ID,
Prodid=product ID

I have a PK (ComID) and an unique key ( VPID,KdID, ProdID, Commission, valid_from, valid_to)



ComID
VPID
KdID
ProdID
Commission
valid_from
valid_to




1
3801


8.00




2
3806


7.00




3
3808


7.00




4
3801
4090
101
4.00
2024-08-01



5
3808


10.00
2024-08-01
2024-08-30



Explanation:

ID 1, 2,3: general commission for the certain customer if no further
exception exists
ID 4: from 2024-08-15 on (until open end) the sales man 3801 gets
for customer 4090 for productID 101 only 4 %
ID 5: in the time range from 2024-07-01 to   2024-08-30 the sales men
3808 gets 10 % for all his customers sales.

My detailed sales table looks like this (sample is simplified and a result from joined tblsales and tblsalesdetails!):



SalesID
InvDate
KdID
ProdID
price
VPID




538
2024-06-05
2895
123
800.00
3801


539
2024-07-03
4090
230
200.00
3808


540
2024-08-05
1234
222
100.00
3808


541
2024-08-05
4090
101
50.00
3801


542
2024-09-07
3456
123
700.00
3808



The result should be:

For salesID 538: 8% * 800 (according to commission ComID 1 = general
commission)
salesID 539:  7% * 200 (ComID 3 general commission)
salesID 540: 10% * 100 (ComID 5 as an exception overrules the general commission)
salesID 541:   4% * 50    (ComID 4 as an exception overrules the general commission)
salesID 542:  7% * 700 (ComID 3 general commission)

With a query I could not solve this problem, I think about using 2 nested loops but I can't define them.
Any idea?
Thanks
I tried to setup nested loops but couldn't work it out.

See if any of the previous questions asked and their answers or comments are of any help: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Your+post+appears+to+contain+code+that+is+not+properly+formatted+as+code%22+answers%3A1

I just copy pasted your question into the ask wizard and it worked with no errors.

Possibly the loose % Chars in "4 %" and "10 %", => remove the Spaces... And/or the 5 parts in 8% * 800 etc, => enclose them between Backticks... Hum, and the 3 parts with = also...

How comes?? I tried it several times and got always the error message. Then I copied the text and made a NEW question - same result. Posting was denied.

Can't really know how or why, the exact rules are kept a secret so people can't game the system. That's why everyone is pretty much guessing here.

@Gimby I don't think these particular rules are being deliberately kept a secret.  They just aren't documented.

Workaround: Add spaces where you have empty cells
Here's a minimal reproduction based on the Markdown source in the question that produces that error (and no other error, due to the text at the top to pad the length):
The following is a table that reproduces the error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."

|ComID| VPID| KdID| ProdID| Commission| valid_from| valid_to |
|--:|-----:|-----:|-------:|----------:|:-----------|:----------|
|1 |3801| ||800 |
|2| 3806||| 700 |
|3| 3808|||700 | 

Adding spaces between the | characters for empty cells seems to make the error go away.  This version works:
The following is a table that does not produce the error "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."

|ComID| VPID| KdID| ProdID| Commission| valid_from| valid_to |
|--:|-----:|-----:|-------:|----------:|:-----------|:----------|
|1 |3801| | |800 |
|2| 3806| | | 700 |
|3| 3808| | |700 | 

As for why: I have no idea.  It appears to be a bug.

It's probably considering the || to be the logical OR operator used in some languages.

Thanks all for your answers.
I wanted to improve my question and post it but surprisingly I was banned by the system!! Which is really strange - after 10 years. So I am not able to try all your suggestions and btw. as I am not a native speaker many things I do not understand - not from the language but from the meaning of the different functions of this site which is very, very complicated to work with, when you are not a regular user.
Anyhow thanks your efforts, I hope to solve my problem without being banned somewhere else because of strange "format issues".

If you're banned from posting that's a completely separate issue related to the quality of your previous questions, see What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?
